# React TypeScript: Map over an array and insert values from an object with a shared key

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In regualr javascript I can do...

```
var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var object = {
  one: 'apple',
  two: 'orange',
  three: 'peach',
  four: 'kiwi',
}

const map1 = array1.map(x => `${object[x]}`);

console.log(map1); // ["apple", "orange", "peach", "kiwi"]
```

**BUT** In react with TypeScript I want to do similar in JSX

```
<ul>
   { state.array1.map( (arrayItem:string, index:number) => (<li key={index} >{state.object[arrayItem]}</li>)) }
</ul>
```

The type script warning is:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any'
>   can't be used to index type '{ one: string; two: string; three:
>   string; four: string;

This is how I declared the object

```
const object: {
    one: string;
    two: string;
    three: string;
    four: string;
}
```

and the array when I mouse over it shows as 

`(property) array1: never[]`

when I save array1 to state it looks like

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({ array1: []});
```

Comment: can you show us how you've declared `array1` and `object`?

Comment: @Ahmad the first two lines?

Comment: @VLAZ OP said that that's how they would do it in regular JavaScript, but they're using typescript.

Comment: @Ahmad and that's what you get if you [use this code in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/G4QwTgBOYgngjBAvBA2gcgPYDsCm6AaCdAFwHdNDiSALMXfI9AM0wFcx0BdAbgChQkTACMAVrgDGJZBADefCBBy4AXMRAAHDQBtGCiOUxqsMbAHM9i2vVXENuEBJqF9rDsYDWASzJeXAXz4+CRwAZ2kAW01EFGg4eAA6KI0ACgAPZAA+CAADABJZEXEpVDSufxyASn5gsMxdBO1MMxTk+GqIAHpOtAAiTR1cXqJezFMLYYhe+0caSd7vX16uIA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `object` only has keys `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`

You are slightly misreading the warning. There are actually two things here, the first one is

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ one: string; two: string; three: string; four: string; }'.

Which simply warns you that `object[x]` is not guaranteed to give you any of its current keys `one`, `two`, `three`, or `four`, so whatever it fetches will be assumed to be `any` type. This basically covers the situation `object["five"]` - since TS does not know of the existence of this property, it cannot guess what the type of it would be - it might be a number, or a string, or simply `undefined`.

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ one: string; two: string; three: string; four: string; }'.

This is what is stopping you. Again, TS only knows of the properties `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four`, however it cannot know that your array contains only those. When you haven't explicitly said what the array contains, it would try to infer [the best common type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type) which in this case is `string`. And since a string is not guaranteed to be any of `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four` (e.g., it might be `five`), then TS cannot guarantee what you do is safe.

You can explicitly say that your array only holds variables that are viable keys:

```js
var array1: Array<'one' | 'two' | 'three'| 'four'> = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var object = {
  one: 'apple',
  two: 'orange',
  three: 'peach',
  four: 'kiwi',
}

const map1 = array1.map(x => `${object[x]}`);

console.log(map1);
```

[Check on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=19#code/G4QwTgBOYgngjALggQTDWAeA5AewHYCm2EAPhNgC4DuuJ5VAFmIcQwGa4CuY2AfBAC8EANp4i2ADQUadaUxbF5nHtgC6AbgBQoSLgBGAK0IBjSkIgBvLRAgFCybCAAOzgDZKbEWY9wx8AOaetpTMrI7OhCAmjFJeKmCOANYAltQpcQC+WlomBADO5gC2LvAW0HDwAHQlzgAUAB5CAgAGACSWBsZmIg1qmS0AlNq5BbgeVW64AXW18MNAA)

Furthermore, if you formally declare what `object`'s type would be, you can use `keyof` instead of manually listing all keys:

```js
interface MyObject {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three: string;
  four: string;
}

var array1: Array<keyof MyObject> = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

var object: MyObject = {
  one: 'apple',
  two: 'orange',
  three: 'peach',
  four: 'kiwi',
}

const map1 = array1.map(x => `${object[x]}`);

console.log(map1);
```

[Check on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=19#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChlkB7ECALmQGcwpQBzAGnOTAHdL6mLEBy5gAFlAh1GzNpwoxKAVygDZwzgF9SpAG5woyA1DjoAjPQCCUE+gA8AawjpKMNFjwEwAPmQBeZABtAHJqCGD2ZGDeSgio8UlwyODFFWCAXQBuHX1DSk9CegwcfEJ-Ei4w+mC4AAdagBsk0T5qyhNhZooEqWraiEQxCK5U1SiHYB5gYe1SBGomZABbOrNy41MzADoV2oAKAA9-XwADABJifNKwQIP0zROASmy5hcomrYbKVj3ds2egA)

Although you could be a bit more informal and not declare a specific type for `object`. This would lead to the following code which will check what the inferred type of `object` is and then make an array of all keys:

```js
var array1: Array<keyof typeof object> = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

var object = {
  one: 'apple',
  two: 'orange',
  three: 'peach',
  four: 'kiwi',
}

const map1 = array1.map(x => `${object[x]}`);

console.log(map1);
```

[Check on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=19#code/G4QwTgBOYgngjALggQTDWAeA1gU1gPYBmEALrAA67EQEBGAVrgMakB8EAvBANoDkBAHa4+AGgh9SAdwJiJpABZhcI8XyIEArmD4BdANwAoQ6Ej0mrLhADehiLWHI+IChQA2qu2RlOCMQQDmnvaKyrhOVCDMCmJeGtpO2ACWUkmxAL7GzEIAzqQQALYu8FbQcPAAdEUUABQAHlwcAAYAJNbmLKQ8dbrpTQCURobZgjkEHhVuBAE11fCDQA)

Your best options are the second and third. The first one is really just there to highlight *why* it doesn't work. `keyof` is interchangeable with `'one' | 'two' | 'three'| 'four'` in this code but it has the benefit of not needing to update multiple places if `object`'s definition changes.

Comment: Note that for the first example you can use the `as const` keyword (TS 3.4+): `var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] as const;`

Comment: I added a link to a sandox showing the issue a bit more clearly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `array1` is considered as an array of string (`string[]`) but `object` does not accept all strings as a key.

Either you need to

- define `array1` as an array of all the possible keys

```
type PossibleKey = 'one' | 'two' | 'three' | 'four';
var array1: PossibleKey[] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var object = {
  one: 'apple',
  two: 'orange',
  three: 'peach',
  four: 'kiwi',
}
const map1 = array1.map(x => `${object[x]}`);
```

- make `object` accept all strings as a key

```
var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var object: Record<string, string> = {
  one: 'apple',
  two: 'orange',
  three: 'peach',
  four: 'kiwi',
}
const map1 = array1.map(x => `${object[x]}`);
```