# React TypeScript: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I save an array to a state and then read it back again I get the error Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]' what is this all about?

I made a code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-pasteur-kj5h0 where the code runs but shows the error in red underlines

Comment: I can't see any error on your codepen? What is the matter?

Comment: Maybe you can see the error here? https://i.imgur.com/LK3rx8n.png

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237601/react-typescript-map-over-an-array-and-insert-values-from-an-object-with-a-shar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you strongly type the generic param for `useState` you're all good

```
const [state, setState] = useState<{ array1: string[] }>({ array1: [] });
```

Comment: you can extract `{ array1: string[] }` to a type to make this easier to read if you prefer.  I inlined it for simplicity

Comment: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ array1: string[]; }>'.
still get this when I try to set a whole array as the new state:             `` ``tempArr.push(...data.data);
setStateOfMyArr(tempArr);``

Comment: looks like you're trying to push an array onto an array instead of concating, but i'd ask a different question